# how to randomly change the color of every pixel on the screen

Tags: java, android

I want each pixel on the screen to flash between red, blue, green, white, and black but independently of each other. Is this possible? I have been searching everywhere with out any luck. Any help on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I looking forward to using your epilepsy test app. ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using images. For example in a 32 bit RGBA image each pixel is made up from 4 parts

```
red = 8 bits
green = 8 bits
blue = 8 bits
alpha = 8 bits
```

Each can be set to a value between 0  and 255;

So you and just treat the image as an array of bytes and change each pixels color values.

```
Image image = CreateImage();

for(int i = 0; i < image.size(); i++)
    image[i] = RandomNumberBetween(0, 255);
```

Or create the image from an array of bytes

```
int byteArray[width * height * 4];

for(int i = 0; i < width * height * 4; i++)
       image[i] = RandomNumberBetween(0, 255);

Image image = createImageFromByteArray(byteArray);
```

You could also create a simple opengl scene and do it in a shader.

```
float rand(vec2 co){
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

void main(void){
     gl_FragColor = rand(gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... its been a while since i've done any java and im new to android dev so sorry for the dumb questions but will these work for android, im not seeing anything on the android site saying that using images is available on the android SDK... it looks like the opengl would work but i don't think im ready to get into that. are there any other ways to get this to work, or could you point out some docs that explain using images with android?

Comment: @BOB before you start asking particular questions, it might help you to read through the Android developer documentation thoroughly.  There is a lot of useful information in there.  A simple search for "image" in the SDK documentation would tell you that there is a thing called an ImageView that displays images.